# Why Trace[] shows some internal warnings on a standard Plot command in V9?

Tags: debugging, error-tracking

For fun, I like to use `Trace` with option `TraceInternal->True` to see if I figure how some of the commands work internally.

I just noticed something strange. In Version 9, I got lots of what seem like error messages that I do not get in Version 8. This example below is using `Plot` (I have not tried many other commands, will do that later).

Consider the most basic plot. See the difference in Trace between V8 and V9:

```
   Trace[Print@Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}], TraceInternal -> True]
```

[image]

ofcourse, the command works just fine at the end in V9, and one gets the plot.

So these messages do not affect the final result, and hence, from a user point of view, one can argue that they should not matter as long as the final result is the same. They could be some internal trace messages that are left there in final build or such?

I am just curious, that is all, if someone might know what they could mean, since they do indicate some sort of an error condition, yet final plot is just fine.

Comment: The `QuantityForm` seems to suggest that the errors result from some pre- or postprocessing for the new `Quantity` and unit support. That more and more seems like a woefully unfinished product.

Comment: No need to use `TraceInternal`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`QuantityForm` (and some other formatting functions) issues messages at typesetting instead of evaluation, and `Trace` is generating output that is in an unevaluated state, which `QuantityForm` isn't expecting.

Here's a couple of similar examples:

```
Trace[Block[{form = "LongForm"}, QuantityForm[Quantity[1, "Meters"], form]]]
Trace[Block[{digits = 3}, NumberForm[N[Pi], digits]]]
```

To be clear, these messages are still coming from the kernel, but during the construction of boxes for the frontend.

```
In[]:= ToBoxes[NumberForm[N[Pi], digits]];5

NumberForm::iprf: Formatting specification digits should be a positive   
    integer or a pair of positive integers.

Out[]= 5
```

and that the messages generally won't appear if the output is suppressed:

```
In[]:= NumberForm[N[Pi], digits];5

Out[]= 5
```

It also means that the messages can be hard to suppress

```
In[]:= Quiet[NumberForm[N[Pi], digits]]

NumberForm::iprf: Formatting specification digits should be a positive 
    integer or a pair of positive integers.

Out[]//NumberForm= 3.14159
```

since `Quiet` goes away once its arguments have finished evaluating, but the problematic form is still present and will still issue messages when formatted.

Comment: The messages generated by these functions go through the kernel or are generated entirely by the FrontEnd and the kernel is not aware about them?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov They're from the kernel.  I updated my answer to explain it a bit better, I hope.

Comment: Thank you. It was not clear for me that the term "at typesetting" should be read as "in the kernel during the construction of boxes for the frontend". Does *typesetting* also always means literal calling `ToBoxes`?